# Performance Test aspects on a Linux Server

Tags: linux, performance, testing, cpu-usage, memory-consumption

We want to do Performance tests on a linux server with and with out antivirus products. Want to understand what are the various aspects to be included while preparing test plan to do performance tests on linux machines. I understand that CPU usage, Memory utilization, Disk IO are some of them. what should i be running continuously in the background to keep machine engaged and what parameters that i should collect.

Comment: krishna check my answer, my own recommendation is Collectl between all these commands and utilities.

Comment: I'd recommend collectl too, but of course I should since I wrote it.  ;)  One of the big benefits of collectl is it is all self-contained so no need to install anything else.  It can record/playback data either on the terminal as text, or as a space-separated file suitable for pulling into a spreadsheet of plotting with gnuplot or any other tool that can deal with this sort of data.  Further if you install colplot (from collectl-utils) it provide a web-based front end to gnuplot making plotting trivial.

Answer (score 0):

There is a script tool from IBM called **lpcpu** which can provided the information you want in graphical display.

Here is the website of **lpcpu**: Click [Linux Performance Customer Profiler Utility](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/wikis/home?lang=en#!/wiki/W51a7ffcf4dfd_4b40_9d82_446ebc23c550/page/Linux+Performance+Customer+Profiler+Utility+%28lpcpu%29"")

This script tool use the following performance tools in Linux. Of course you need to manually install some tools in advance before running lpcpu.

- iostat
- mpstat
- vmstat
- perf
- meminfo
- top
- sar
- oprofile
- perf

All you need to do is issuing `./lpcpu.sh duration=30`. It will monitor your system for 30 seconds and give you a tar ball archive file. Afterward what you need to do is extract the tar ball, run the `./postprocess.sh <location_of_lpcpu>`. Then you can use a browser to inspect the graphical performance characteristics of your system.

I believe lpcpu is a good start point for you to inspect the characteristics of your system/application.